# Automatic update table by jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I succeed in populating the table dynamically with JSON data. The problem now is how to update the table with new data every a certain amount of time. I tried to cancel the table before creating a new one with new data, but it seems to not be working. When I try the code below, the table is not populated. Could you help me?

```
function loadTable(){
    $('#mytable tbody tr').remove();
    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) { 
            $('#mytable tr').eq(i).after('<tr><td>'+val.value0+'</td><td>'+ 
               val.n_users+ '</td><td>'+val.value1+'/'+val.value2+ 
               '</td><td>10:59 08/01/2014</td></tr>');
        });
    });
    setTimeout("loadTable()",15000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work, is that you are removing all of the `tr` elements, and then trying to add code based on `tr` elements:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').remove();
```

and:

```
$('#mytable tr').eq(i).after(...);
```

By this time, there are no `tr`'s, so this line does nothing.  Instead, simply append `tr`'s, instead of trying to modify existing ones:

```
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON('sort.php', function (data) {
        $('#mytable tbody tr').remove();
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            $('#mytable').append('<tr><td>' + val.value0 + '</td><td>' + val.n_users + '</td><td>' + val.value1 + '/' + val.value2 + '</td><td>10:59 08/01/2014</td></tr>');
        });
    });
    setTimeout("loadTable()", 15000);
}
```

If the number of rows will always be the same, you can modify existing rows, but you need to make sure not to delete them:

```
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON('sort.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            $('#mytable tr').eq(i).html('<td>' + val.value0 + '</td><td>' + val.n_users + '</td><td>' + val.value1 + '/' + val.value2 + '</td><td>10:59 08/01/2014</td>');
        });
    });
    setTimeout("loadTable()", 15000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  When you find an answer useful, you can up-vote the answer with the arrows on the left.  If you choose an answer as the correct one, click the check mark next to the number on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function loadTable() {

    $.getJSON('sort.php', function (data) {
        $('#mytable tbody tr').remove();
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            $('#mytable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + val.value0 + '</td><td>' + val.n_users + '</td><td>' + val.value1 + '/' + val.value2 + '</td><td>10:59 08/01/2014</td></tr>');
        });
    });
    setTimeout("loadTable()", 15000);
}
```

And it's best that you don't empty the table until the ajax is done (I moved the line)

Comment: This looks like it should solve the OP's problem, but it would be nice if you stated why it fixed the problem.

Comment: True.  "after" returns a string, but won't change the HTML.  "append" will change the HTML.